# How to update the default value in flask form or html page from sql alchemy (currently getting updated only when restarting the server)?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, python-requests, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

How to store the default values in flask form the sqlalchemy?

**Form.py**

```
> class EditPasswordPolicyForm(FlaskForm):    
>     get_row = PolicyCheck.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
>     greater = IntegerField('greater',default = get_row.greaterthan)
>     lesser = IntegerField('lesser',default = get_row.lessthan)
>     special = BooleanField('special',default=get_row.specialChar)
>     upper = BooleanField('upper',default=get_row.isupper)
>     lower = BooleanField('lower',default=get_row.islower)
>     digit = BooleanField('digit',default=get_row.isdigit)
>     update = SubmitField('update')
```

**model.py**

> > ```
> > class Policy(db.Model):
> > id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
> > greaterthan = db.Column(db.Integer)
> > lessthan = db.Column(db.Integer)
> > specialChar = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
> > isupper = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
> > islower = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
> > isdigit = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True)
> > ```

**view.html**

```
> <div>   {{ form.greater.label(class="form-control-label") }} 
>                              {{ form.greater(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
>                    </div>
```

**routes.py**

```
> @app.route("/edit_password_policy",methods=['GET', 'POST'] ) def
> edit_password_policy():
>     form = EditPasswordPolicyForm()
>     if form.validate_on_submit(): 
>         response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api_view',
>                         json={
>                         "greater_than": form.greater.data,
>                         "lesser_than": form.lesser.data,
>                         "special_character": form.special.data,
>                         "upper_case": form.upper.data,
>                         "lower_case": form.lower.data,
>                         "digit": form.digit.data
>                         }
>                         )  if response.json()['status'] == 'SUCCESS':
>             flash(response.json()['msg'], 'success')
>             return redirect(url_for('home'))
>         else:
>             print("Failed")
>             flash(response.json()['msg'], 'danger') return render_template('view.html', title='edit_password_policy', form=form)
```

**api.py**

```
> class EditPasswordPolicy(Resource):
>     """ EditPasswordPolicy Api """
>     def post(self):
>         
>         data = request.json  # parser.parse_args()
>         print(data["lesser_than"])
>         
>         if data:
>             db.session.commit() #need to check json exits or not
>             Greater=request.json['greater_than']
>             Less=request.json['lesser_than']
>             Special=request.json['special_character']
>             Upper=request.json['upper_case']
>             Lower=request.json['lower_case']
>             Digit=request.json['digit']           
> 
>             policy = PolicyCheck.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
> 
>             policy.greaterthan = Greater
>             policy.lessthan = Less
>             policy.specialChar = Special
>             policy.isupper = Upper
>             policy.islower = Lower
>             policy.isdigit = Digit
>             db.session.commit()
```

In **forms.py** I am assigning default values from the **sqlalcehmy** database and it is working correctly. But the problem is when I changes the values in **view.html** form (from 8 to 10) and click on submit it get updated in the database, but value from the database is not getting updated as default values in **view.html**  (still showing 8 only, I also refreshed the page). When I restarted the local server it gets updated to correct value from 8 to 10.

Now I need to update the default value to 10 without restarting the server.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
class EditPasswordPolicyForm(FlaskForm):

    greater = IntegerField('greater')
    lesser = IntegerField('lesser')
    special = BooleanField('special')
    upper = BooleanField('upper')
    lower = BooleanField('lower')
    digit = BooleanField('digit')
    update = SubmitField('update')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditPasswordPolicyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        get_row = PolicyCheck.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
        self.greater.default = get_row.greaterthan
        self.lesser.default = get_row.lessthan
        self.special.default = get_row.specialChar
        self.upper.default = get_row.isupper
        self.lower.default = get_row.islower
        self.digit.default = get_row.isdigit
```

If it is not work, you can try change `self.greater.default` to `self.greater.data` for all form variables.

Comment: I think what happening here in the flaskform  is , it is not looking into the  database after the initial run. So the default values are not getting updated.

Comment: The `__init__` method will definitely run when you instantiate the `EditPassWordPolicyForm` object, so it will definitely get the latest data from the database.

Comment: Yes it should be, but only restarting the server is updaiting the form default values.

Comment: After Clicking the submit , the page get refreshed and it should be updated with updated values as defaults.

Comment: How I solved this is, in routes.py after validation on submit, I gave form.greaterthan.data = policy.greaterthan ,So I will get the updated values by default.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this

class EditPasswordPolicyForm(FlaskForm):

```
greater = IntegerField('greater')
lesser = IntegerField('lesser')
special = BooleanField('special')
upper = BooleanField('upper')
lower = BooleanField('lower')
digit = BooleanField('digit')
update = SubmitField('update')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EditPasswordPolicyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    get_row = PolicyCheck.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    self.greater.default = get_row.greaterthan
    self.lesser.default = get_row.lessthan
    self.special.default = get_row.specialChar
    self.upper.default = get_row.isupper
    self.lower.default = get_row.islower
    self.digit.default = get_row.isdigit
```

Now the html fields are showing the default values as what I entered and I refreshed page again values are showing correctly and also there is no problem with updating the values in the database. But When I navigate to other html page and comes back to this page, all the fields becomes blank. I want to show the default values now also.

and again I tried the second approach by changeing

> self.greater.default

to

> self.greater.data

for all form variables.

Here also the html fields are showing the default values as what I entered.
Now the values were not getting updated in the database, but after navigation its showing old values from database.(not the values what I entered in html form)